# Multiple Viewports on OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, viewport

I'm trying to make a racecar game, and I'm having a problem on showing multiple viewports on the screen. I wish to put on the down right corner of the screen a small "mini-map" (that would acctually be a different view from the main camera scene) but somewhy, the second viewport just does not appears, and all I can see is the view of the main camera.

Here follows my code as is:

```
    void mainRender() {
        updateState();

        setViewport(0, windowWidth, 0, windowHeight);
        setWindow();
        renderScene();


        setViewport(0, windowWidth, 0, windowHeight/2);
        renderScene();
        gluLookAt(0,88,0,
                  1 ,0 ,0,
                  0.0,1.0,0.0);



        Sleep(30);
    }

    void setWindow() {
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)windowWidth/(GLfloat)windowHeight,0.1f, 100.0f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluLookAt(posX,posY + 0.025 * std::abs(sin(headPosAux*PI/180)),posZ,
        posX + sin(roty*PI/180),posY + 0.025 * std::abs(sin(headPosAux*PI/180)) + cos(rotx*PI/180),posZ -cos(roty*PI/180),
        0.0,1.0,0.0);

    }

    void setViewport(GLint left, GLint right, GLint bottom, GLint top){
        glViewport(left, bottom, right - left, top - bottom);
     }


    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
        glutInitWindowSize(windowWidth,windowHeight);
        glutInitWindowPosition(windowXPos,windowYPos);

        /**
        Store main window id so that glui can send it redisplay events
        */
        mainWindowId = glutCreateWindow("TF");

        glutDisplayFunc(mainRender);

        glutReshapeFunc(onWindowReshape);

        /**
        Register keyboard events handlers
        */
        glutKeyboardFunc(onKeyDown);
        glutKeyboardUpFunc(onKeyUp);



        mainInit();

        glutMainLoop();

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What are you drawing into the second viewport? I don't see any code that actually draws anything.

Comment: Go here, there is a downloadable ViewPort example.  http://zavie.free.fr/opengl/index.html.en#viewports

Comment: I don't draw in the second viewport, I just change the position of the camera, so it can look to the map from upwards and it will look like a minimap (that's what I use the lookAt function for).

Comment: I've changed my code (now it does draw the whole scene again) and updated my question, but the same problem persists, I only see one viewport.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't draw in the second viewport, I just change the position of the camera, so it can look to the map from upwards and it will look like a minimap (that's what I use the lookAt function for).

I think you've got some serious misunderstanding of how opengl works. Just changing the gluLookAt won't do anything. If you want to view the scene from a different angle, you have to redraw the entire scene once you've changed the viewport. If you want to show a minimap then you should draw your whole scene normally, set the viewport to the minimap, set the overhead camera, and then draw the whole scene again.

Comment: I've changed my code and updated my question, but the same problem persists, I only see one viewport.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start using `glGetError`.

Your left and right argument to your function is mixed up. You're passing left as width/2, and right as 0. This is generating a negative width, and thus an error. Your height also looks negative.

Comment: your understanding of glViewport may be incorrect, it is x, y, width, height. not left right, top, bottom! Although I think that your assessment may be correct as they are confusing things with their own setViewport method.

Comment: You were right, I've fixed that. Still, it looks like the second viewport call just makes the first viewport disappear, now all I see is the second viewport (the area of the screen where the other one should be is black).